# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes after login except with nomodeset

Tags: unity, nvidia, login

I just downloaded and installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 for my Sony Vaio Z Series laptop.

After the installation finished, a message asked me to restart. When I clicked on it, it just froze, so I shut down the laptop directly using the shutdown key.

Once I rebooted the laptop, I can log in a as guest without any problem (although it freezes when changing language or logout).

But I can't open my user account; I enter the password, click <kbd>log in</kbd>, then it freezes, although I still can move the cursor.

I executed `apt-get install unity` and `dpkg-reconfigure`, I've also tried `apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`.

I have the same problem with Ubuntu 17.04. I installed 16.04 and 17.04 twice, but still can't fix this issue.

I've also tried `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but it didn't help.

After setting the kernel boot parameters to `quiet splash nomodeset`, I can log in, but the problem is that with `nomodeset` the resolution is annoying.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you install a video driver? If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, does it also freeze in the same way? Also, check the Sony web site to see if there's a BIOS update available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to install nvidia drivers, but it's just messed up now. I now can log in with the nomodeset disabled, but now it freezes on shutdown, so again I use the shutdown key to restart... and when I do, it switches back to nomodeset.

Comment: Please clarify. Is "quiet splash nomodeset" still set? Where did you get the Nvidia drivers from... their web site, or the Ubuntu repos? The shutdown freeze may be a different problem. Did you check the BIOS? Does the Live DVD work properly?

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get install nvidia-370` in the `ppa:graphics-drivers` repository.

How to check the BIOS? , for the installation I created a Live USB after I downloded ubuntu from the website.

Comment: `quiet slash nomodeset` is still set, even if I remove `nomodeset` from grub, I find it there whenever the computer reboots.

Comment: Did you edit /etc/default/grub and then `sudo update-grub`? To check the BIOS, enter the BIOS at power on time, note the current version #, go to the Sony web site... support/downloads... enter your model #, look for BIOS updates, compare to your version.

Comment: Ah, yes .. I forgot to `update-grub`, thank you so much .. I'll check the BIOS once I finish reinstalling nvidia drivers. +1

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved the problem, I added the answer. Best !

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the problem. Here's what I did exactly:

Since this happened after installing Ubuntu 16.04, and because nvidia drivers got messed up (as I was trying to solve the problem), I decided to reinstall Ubuntu again and try another solution.

1. I installed Ubuntu
2. With my new clean installation, I opened the GRUB menu by pressing the right <kbd>shift</kbd> key on reboot.
3. In the GRUB menu, I browsed with arrow keys to `Ubuntu`, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot parameters.
4. I browsed to the line starting with `linux`, and added `nomodeset` after `quiet splash`. Then pressed <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
5. Now I could log in using my user account, I entered the password and got access to my desktop.
6. I searched for **System Settings** in the launcher, then **Software & Updates**, I set *download from* to *Main Server*. Then opened **Additional Drivers** tab, and checked one of the *Nvidia (Proprietary, tested)* drivers.
7. It took a very long time for *Applying changes* to finish (about an hour), and once it finished, I rebooted as normal (without `nomodeset`), and this time I could access to my user account.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The following commands worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Hopefully it will work on your computer too.

Comment: Thank you so much,  +1 , check my answer to see how I fixed my problem, because reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and installing unity didn't work for me.